# Back button returns empty value of dropdown in IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

Hi i have drop down field on one form,which send data to another form say searchresult.aspx
However, if one clicks on  back button  in Internet Explorer, all the fields default.aspx get cleared. I have stored drop down value in Hidden field,but it is also get empty when navigating through back button.
It works fine with Firefox and Chrome.
Anyone has an idea , what I have to do to make it work?
Im using jquery mobile using Asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Could be IE is caching the blank page and pulling that when you hit the back button, using fiddler you can see if it's loading the page or pulling from cache.  Otherwise try saving the dropdown value in a session before you go to the next page, when you come back to the search page update the code to check the session value, if there use that to select the dropdown otherwise if not there then select the default value.

Comment: I tried to remove jquery mobile reference and it worked, so the probolem is of jquery mobile with IE